# How do I restrict access to my ContentProvider to only my apps?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contentresolver

I want to export a ContentProvider for use by another one of MY apps. How do I prevent other apps from accessing it? If I use an android:permission attribute, can't 3rd party apps just apply that permission to their app? I really need to lock down access to my apps only.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> If I use an android:permission attribute, can't 3rd party apps just apply that permission to their app?

Well, you can use a `signature`-level custom permission (`android:protectionLevel="signature"`). Then, the app holding the permission and the app defending itself with the permission have to be signed by the same signing key.

There's a bug/limitation in Android that can allow an attacker, installed before your app, to hold this permission even though the attacker is not signed by your signing key. I go into that in more detail in [this report](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/blob/master/PERMS.md) (as it's a bit complex for an SO answer) and have [a `PermissionUtils` class](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-security/#usage-checkcustompermissions) to help you detect that case.